# Webservices In Apple Iphone connection

Tags: iphone

Am having a webservice. Need my apple code to connect and pass 3parameters to the web service. Am very new to Objective C. Can anyone provide a sample code or guide me through this? Have searched links in StackOverflow. But not able to understand them.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Search **"How to implement web service in iPhone"** in google. Please search on Google before asking direct questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You using soap message okey then akshar first you create a class of NSObject and then define a method in .h file with 3 parameter as given in below code:-

in .h file

```
@interface GetPartParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
    NSMutableArray *getPartArr;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSString *currentElement;
    NSMutableString *part_urlStr, *partNameStr;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *getPartArr;
-(void) fetchPartXMLData:(NSInteger)empid:(NSInteger)serid:(NSInteger)seaid:(NSInteger)episodeid;
```

and in .m file :-

```
-(void) fetchPartXMLData:(NSInteger)empid:(NSInteger)serid:(NSInteger)seaid :(NSInteger)episodeid
{
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservices.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: myURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             "<GetPart xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                             "<empid>%d</empid>"
                             "<serid>%d</serid>"
                             "<seaid>%d</seaid>"
                             "<episodeId>%d</episodeId>"
                             "</GetPart>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>",empid,serid,seaid,episodeid];
    NSLog(@"soapMessage :%@",soapMessage);
    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetPart" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMessage length]];
    [request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLResponse *returnedResponse = nil;
    NSError *returnedError = nil;
    NSData *barData  = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&returnedResponse error:&returnedError];
    NSString *barString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[barData bytes] length:[barData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"barString :%@",[[barString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"]);

    NSData* data=[[[barString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];       
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [xmlParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [xmlParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [xmlParser parse];
}
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    getPartArr =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code %i )", [parseError code]];
    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    {
        currentElement = [elementName copy];
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"part"])
        {
            item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            part_urlStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
            partNameStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        }
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"part_url"])
    {
        [part_urlStr appendString:string];
    }
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"partName"])
    {
        [partNameStr appendString:string];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"part"])
    {
        [item setObject:part_urlStr forKey:@"part_url"];
        [item setObject:partNameStr forKey:@"partName"];
        [getPartArr addObject:[item copy]];
    }
    NSLog(@"item dictionary....%@",partNameStr);
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{    
    NSLog(@"getPartArr :%@",getPartArr);

}
```

it helps you and give what you want...
if you like then mark it as accepted

Comment: ok.. Thank you.. Will try this out and let you know. And is there any way to know whether the parameters are accepted by the service through our iphone app? also i need to pass through proxy settings. this method works with that rt?

Comment: when you pass your 3 parameters then you got the response from server just NSLog the response and see it in console window ...

Comment: its working fine. and i should put the NSLog in DidRecieve Response rt? but it is giving authentication error. not able to pass through PROXY...

Answer (score 1):

```
   NSString *urlString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://demo.xyz.com/proj/webservices/display_records/1/%@%@%@",myid,name,password];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
conn= [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(conn)
{
    webdata=[[NSMutableData data]retain];
}
```

Use defalut connection methods

Comment: what is conn? A sample code ll be good. and am trying out things here. but am able to hit the webservice. but dont know how to make sure it has invoked the right service or not? Am using XML and soap messages.

Comment: Its basic.You can make out from the code.conn is the object of NSURLConnection type.Can you display the output so we can get closer?

Answer (score 0):

An event simpler way to get a ws result is:

```
NSString *urlString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://demo.xyz.com/proj/webservices/display_records/1/%@%@%@",myid,name,password];
NSString *wsRes = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlStribng encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Consider extending this sample with error handling if you are going to use it.